# How can I go decrement the iterator of a std::map by a certain number?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator, std

With an std::vector I can do:

```
std::vector<int> h;
auto it = h.end() - 2;
```

But with the std::map I can't do:

```
std::map<int, int> h;
auto it = h.end() - 2;
```

I can only do:

```
auto it = --h.end();
```

This is for example if I want the member two from the end, or three from the end, or whatever.

Comment: Different containers have different [*iterator categories*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories). Some iterators can do more, some can do less.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

```
auto it = h.end();
std::advance(it, -4);
```

Note that the complexity is **linear** in `n` (the second parameter) for `std::map` iterators (which are not random access iterators), meaning that there is no "magic" and a call to `std::advance` is equivalent to applying `n` times the increment/decrement operator on the iterator.

Comment: "We're Not Retreating; We're Advancing in a Different Direction" -- General Oliver P. Smith, Korean War

Comment: @Yakk Haha what? Thank you, Holt.

Comment: You can also use `std::prev` if you want the quote to be less elicited :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why wouldn't the first version work?

Comment: @Zebrafish Because `std::advance` is `void`, you can't assign its result to anything. `std::next()` or `std::prev()` would work, though, because they do not touch the original iterator.

Comment: @Zebrafish Because unlike `std::prev` or `std::next`, `std::advance` does not return the iterator after modifying it, it only modifies its argument.

Comment: @Zebrafish Remember to check that you do not pass the "end" (or rather, the *beginning*).

Answer (score 7):

On the other hand, you can also use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), as follows:

```
auto it = std::prev(iter, 2);
```

Internally, this does the same thing as `std::advance` (using it, in fact), except it could be said that this is somewhat clearer.

If you were wondering why you couldn't subtract a map iterator unlike a vector iterator, the reason for this is because `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), meaning it "can be moved to point to any element in constant time"<sup>1</sup> through addition/subtraction. On the other hand, `std::map<T,U>::iterator` is a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which can go in either direction, but only in increments of one.

<sup>1</sup> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator

Answer (score 1):

The template class `std::vector` has random access iterators for which the operation `h.end() - 2` is defined.

On the other hand the template class `std::map` has bidirectional iterators for which the operation `h.end() - 2` is not defined.

If you include the header `<iterator>` you can use standard functions `std::next` and `std::prev` as for random access iterators and for bidirectional iterators.

For example

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

//...

std::map<int, int> h;
//...
auto it = std::prev( h.end(), 2 );
```

and

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

//...

std::vector<int> h;
//...
auto it = std::prev( h.end(), 2 );
```